# drupal_add_js not working in hook_user_login

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7 I am adding js using drupal_add_js from within hook_user_login.

After adding the js I can call drupal_get_js() and I can see that my js has been added, but when the page is loading the js has gone.

My code is:

```
function popups_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
    $js = 'some inline js here';
    drupal_add_js($js, array('type'=>'inline', 'weight'=>1));
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'popups').'/popups.js', array('weight'=>2));
}
```

The aim of the module is to create a popup once the user has logged in if certain criteria are met.

There is a similar question on drupal.org [just here](http://drupal.org/node/1372506).

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

(I've tried this on 2 separate Drupal 7 installs and have experienced the same problem on both sites)

Comment: Most likely you've got something set up to redirect to a certain page after login...so you're adding the js in the first page request, a redirect happens, and the next page doesn't have your js added

Comment: Spot on - I installed Devel and turned on "Display redirection page" and I was indeed being redirected after login. Strangely I being redirected from the homepage back to the homepage...

Comment: My solution here was to set a session variable in hook_user_login and then check if that is set in hook_page_alter and then add the JS at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Clive said this was due to a redirect happening directly after login. 
This can be checked by installing Devel and turning on "Display redirection page" on the Devel settings page.

The solution is to set a session variable in hook_user_login (which in my case contained the nids of the popups I want to display), which can then be read in hook_page_alter and add the necessary JS added at this point.